How to write code on Windows and build/hot reload/hot restart on MAC?
I currently have an old Mac and a Windows desktop. I prefer to develop and write code on my Windows machine because it's much faster than my 8GB RAM Mac.
My current setup is to share the project folder over my local network. I access it from my Mac to run the project.
The problem is that they overwrite each other when I run pub get or build. Is there a way I can develop on Windows and use hot reload/hot restart on the Mac?
Using Git is one option, but it feels like overkill if I have to commit a small change just to hot reload.

This is probably something you want to set up with a script.  Your script could run from your Windows PC via SSH to the Mac.  You could set this up in your IDE such that you just trigger the script to run, and then copy over whatever files are changed.  Maybe even something like a one-way rsync would be more useful for you.

Hey thanks for the suggestion. It worked!

Glad to hear it!

Thanks to @Brad suggestions, I set up rsync on windows and ssh in my mac. Step by step instructions below:

Install an SSH Server on Your Mac (if it’s not already enabled):


Open System Preferences > Sharing.
Check Remote Login to enable SSH access.
Add the path you want to share to windows here.
Note your Mac’s IP address or hostname shown here (you’ll need it for destination in the script).


Install rync
Create rsync script in Windows. My final script looks something like this.



#!/bin/bash

# Define source and destination paths
SOURCE="/c/path/to/windowsdev/"  # Adjust this path to your specific source folder on Windows
DESTINATION="user@host:/path/to/macdev/"  # Use your Mac's username and host, and the correct path

# Run rsync to sync changes, excluding specific directories
rsync -avz --delete \
--exclude '.idea/' \
--exclude '.dart_tool/' \
--exclude 'build/' \
"$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION"




Why dont you just execute hot reload, hot restart or even build your projects in windows if your windows have better specifications?
Also, what do you mean by overwrite each other, maybe you can explain more?

I need to run on mac to test ios devices.
To explain overwrite, when run pub get/build/run on mac, it will make project on windows run pub get again. I'm guessing this behavior because those command overwrite files within project.
